# How can i tell IntelliJ's code formatter to ignore long lines that end in a comment?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm trying to add code formatting rules to a project in which some of the Java code contains trailing comments.

Example 1:

```
private int foo1 = 123;
private int foo2 = 123;
private int foo3 = 123; // yadda yadda
private int foo4 = 123;
```

Example 2:

```
someMethodCall(firstParameter,
               secondParameter,  // yadda yadda
               thirdParameter);
```

In some cases, the comment extends across the right margin, and when reformatting code, the comment will be broken up and partly moved to the next line.

I'd like IntelliJ to avoid reformatting long lines if it's a trailing comment causing it to go over the limit. I'd also like to keep the long-line reformat on otherwise, so disabling it altogether is not an option.

IntelliJ offers [an option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html#formatter_options) to disable formatting for certain regions of code. This is toggled on/off by specified strings/regular expression patterns. I have tried using `//` as the value for "Formatter off" and `\n` as the value for "Formatter on" both with and without the "Regular expressions" option checked. In either case, it doesn't work as expected and certain parts of the file/selection will be automatically reformatted while other parts will not.

Are there any values for the formatter toggle markers that will do what I want? If not, is there an option somewhere else that can do this?

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.